# Overflow in DL - dimensions of poup window don't adjust automatically

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
.content {
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0px 0px -250px;
    }

    dl {

    }

    dl dt {
    float: left;
    }

    dl dd {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

And HTML

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Title</h1>
<dl>
<dt>tab 1</dt>
<dd>content content</dd>

<dt>tab 2</dt>
<dd>content content </dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

This is pop-up with tabs. The problem is... to DD (tab content) I add position: absolute, but most of all text is out of the window... I know that DT height is NOT flexible... it isn't adjust automatically to contents (dt and dd)... I tried overflow: hidden etc. and I can't get proper effect. Could someone help me?

Comment: is the text inside a paragraph?

Comment: Just in <dd>, should I place it to <p>?

Comment: <p> should adapt itself to the div in which it is inside an not go out of the window

Answer (score 0):

A block element's auto height will ignore floating elements. This can be remedied with a quick clearing pseudo-element:

```
#element::after { content:""; display:block; clear:both; }
```

Expressed alternatively, elements with `float:left;` (or right obvs) can overflow the bounds of a container that has `height:auto;`. The solution involves creating a new `::after` CSS pseudo-element that can `clear:both;` any floating children (and `display:block;` and `content:"";` because they make the pseudo-element behave as a block, and it's mandatory for pseudo-elements, respectively).

---

**In your case, try adding this to the end of your CSS file:**

```
.content::after, dl::after {content:"";display:block;clear:both;}
```

I'm not sure if that will help though, I'm not sure what that whole situation would render like.